# Combining 3 SQL Queries into a Single Query

Tags: query, sql

I'm facing a challenge with my SQL query in Marketing Cloud and would appreciate the community's help in resolving it.

Recently, I created three separate Data Extensions as part of a segmentation. To achieve this, I ran three different SQL queries. The goal is to merge these three queries into a single query to store the resulting data in a single Data Extension.

**Here are the three queries I used:**

1. ```
    Select FirstName, LastName, city, Subscriberkey, 
    EmailAdress

    FROM [Segment1]

    WHERE City IS NULL 

    OR City NOT LIKE '%Denver%'
   ```

2. ```
    Select FirstName, LastName, city, Subscriberkey, EmailAdress
    FROM [Segment1]
    WHERE City LIKE '%Denver%'
    and EmailAddress NOT IN 
     (Select EmailAddress from Contacts_segment)
   ```
3. ```
     Select FirstName, LastName, city, Subscriberkey, EmailAddress
     from [Segment2]
     WHERE 
     EmailAddress NOT IN 
     (Select EmailAddress from [Contacts_segment]
     UNION
     Select EmailAddress from [Contact_data])
   ```

**Here is my attempt to combine these 3 queries into a single query:**

```
    SELECT
    
    FirstName, LastName, city, Subscriberkey, EmailAddress         
    
    'Segment1' AS Segment 
    
    FROM [Segment1]
    
    WHERE City IS NULL 
    
    OR City NOT LIKE '%Denver%'

     UNION

    SELECT

     FirstName, LastName, city, Subscriberkey, EmailAddress
 
    'Segment2' AS Segment 

    FROM [Segment1]

   WHERE City LIKE '%Denver%'

   UNION 

    SELECT 

    FirstName, LastName, city, Subscriberkey, EmailAddress
 
   'Segment3' AS Segment 

    FROM [Segment2]
```

**Note:** The fields in my target Data Extension are the same as the ones I'm selecting in my SELECT statement (FirstName, LastName, City, Subscriberkey, EmailAddress), with the only difference being the inclusion of a field (Segment) to identify which segment the contacts are coming from. My only primary key is the Subscriberkey to ensure that they are unique contacts.

I'm facing an issue where the final numbers in the resulting Data Extension do not match the sum of the three original Data Extensions. There seems to be some problem with my final query, but I can't identify it. The situation may be a bit confusing, but I'm confident that someone here can help me resolve this issue. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your patience, I'm new to Marketing Cloud and I'm trying to learn more.

Comment: I only see two data extensions referenced in your queries, not three -- Segment1 and Segment2.

Comment: Also, not sure how you verified the counts as the combined query has a couple of syntax errors that would prevent it from running.  And is `EmailAdress` a typo?

Comment: Please update your question to include the details about the target data extension, including the primary key fields.

Comment: @Adam Spriggs 
Yes, I'm using only 2 Data Extensions as a source, but I've created 3 segments. Segment 3 is the one that doesn't have a corresponding email address in the other two tables, [Contacts_segment] and [Contact_data].

Comment: And yes, I wrote EmailAddress wrong. So it's a typo, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you build a simple model outside of Marketing Cloud first -- instead of trying match counts.  It's easier to look at the data and determine the desired outcomes *before writing the query*.

Here's a simplified mock-up query using dbfiddle:

**1. Prepare the sample tables and add rows to them**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Segment1 (City varchar(40), Subscriberkey varchar(254), EmailAddress varchar(254));
CREATE TABLE Segment2 (City varchar(40), Subscriberkey varchar(254), EmailAddress varchar(254));
CREATE TABLE Contacts_segment (EmailAddress varchar(254));
CREATE TABLE Contact_Data (EmailAddress varchar(254));
INSERT INTO  Segment1 (City,Subscriberkey,EmailAddress) VALUES 
  (null,'SK1','email1@example.com')
, ('Boulder','SK2','email2@example.com')
, ('Aurora','SK3','email3@example.com')
, ('Lakewood','SK4','email4@example.com')
, ('Denver','SK5','email5@example.com')
INSERT INTO  Segment2 (City,Subscriberkey,EmailAddress) VALUES 
  ('Durango','SK6','email6@example.com')
, ('Denver','SK7','email7@example.com')
, ('Aurora','SK8','email8@example.com')
, ('Aspen','SK9','email9@example.com')
, ('Denver','SK0','email0@example.com')
INSERT INTO  Contacts_segment (EmailAddress) VALUES 
 ('email7@example.com')
INSERT INTO  Contact_data (EmailAddress) VALUES 
 ('email8@example.com')
```

**2. Run your test queries against the sample data:**

```sql
SELECT
  City
, Subscriberkey
, EmailAddress
, 'Segment1' AS Segment
FROM Segment1
WHERE
City IS NULL 
OR City NOT LIKE '%Denver%'

UNION

SELECT
  City
, Subscriberkey
, EmailAddress
, 'Segment2' AS Segment
FROM Segment1
WHERE 
City LIKE '%Denver%'
and EmailAddress NOT IN (
  Select
  EmailAddress
  from Contacts_segment
)

UNION

SELECT
  City
, Subscriberkey
, EmailAddress
, 'Segment3' AS Segment
FROM Segment2
where
EmailAddress NOT IN (

  Select
  EmailAddress
  from Contacts_segment

  UNION

  Select
  EmailAddress
  from Contact_data

)
```

**3. Verify the results are as you expected:**

| City | Subscriberkey | EmailAddress | Segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | SK1 | email1@example.com | Segment1 |
| Aspen | SK9 | email9@example.com | Segment3 |
| Aurora | SK3 | email3@example.com | Segment1 |
| Boulder | SK2 | email2@example.com | Segment1 |
| Denver | SK0 | email0@example.com | Segment3 |
| Denver | SK5 | email5@example.com | Segment2 |
| Durango | SK6 | email6@example.com | Segment3 |
| Lakewood | SK4 | email4@example.com | Segment1 |

[Try it yourself on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9BjxjJ23)

Comment: This tool is really useful. I'm still getting the hang of Marketing Cloud, but when I need to work on more robusts tasks, I'll definitely give this tool a try.
Thanks.